# TabView "dot" index color does not change

Tags: swift, swiftui

If you use `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))` then your tab bar will be displayed as a group of dots, indicating you current page index.
By default it has white color and I can't change it.
In code below I'll show all my tries around this problem (none of them works). The main question: how to change the dots color?
PS: Important notice! On preview I see these changes, but when starts the simulator then the colouring disappears.

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("Home Tab")
            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .tabItem {
                Text("Home")
            }
     
        Text("Bookmark Tab")
            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .tabItem {
                Text("Bookmark")
            }
    }
    .onAppear(){
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .blue;
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .red;
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red;
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
   }
}
```

```
[![ColorImage][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P25ST.png
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `init` instead of `onAppear`

```
struct TestScrollView: View {
    init() {
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .blue
        UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = .red
        UIPageControl.appearance().tintColor = .red
    }
    var body: some View {
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Why onAppear is not acceptable here?

Comment: @EmiliaLarssen `onAppear` is called after `init` and is usually too late for configuring `appearance()`

Comment: @EmiliaLarssen, the View is created with whatever you've set in init. That means it will initially be drawn with the default values for the UIPageControl.appearance() settings. Changing these values in .onAppear does not change the View's State so a redraw of the view with the new colors doesn't occur. You could manually trigger a redraw in .onAppear by changing a State variable but that's not recommended because you're then trying to manually control when drawing occurs.

Comment: Is there a way to change the color based on the color scheme (light, dark)? Accessing the environment variable from init won't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply don't want to mess with UIKit on SwiftUI, or you need to give the color after init:

**Create your own! and have total style control**

[image]

```
@State private var tabSelection = 0

var body: some View {
 ZStack(alignment:.bottom){
    TabView(selection: $tabSelection.animation()){
                                Text("Slide 1")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(0)
                                Text("Slide 2")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(1)
                                Text("Slide 3")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(2)
                            }
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
     HStack(spacing: 6){
              ForEach(0..<3) { i in
                  Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                      .font(.system(size: 9))
                      .foregroundStyle(tabSelection == i ? .black : .gray)
               }
     }
                            .padding(.bottom)
 }
}
```